# Java - Get repeated array elements and their repetition number

Tags: java, arrays

I want to extract and count the repeated array elements as in example:

```
int arr []= {7,4,3,0,2,0,5,2,13,2,0,3};
```

the output should be

> 2 repeated 3 times
>
> 0 repeated 3 times
>
> 3 repeated 2 times

There is my trial code in Java:

```
public static void repeated(int x[]){
        int i, j;
        int counter = 0;
        for(i=0 ; i<x.length ; i++ ){
            boolean isRepeat = false;
            for(j=i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--){
                if(x[i] == x[j]){
                    isRepeat = true;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if(isRepeat){
                counter = counter+1;
                System.out.println(x[i] + " repeated " + counter + " times");
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr []= {7,4,3,0,2,0,5,2,13,2,0,3};
        repeated(arr);
    }
```

but My output is:

> 0 repeated 2 times
>
> 2 repeated 2 times
>
> 2 repeated 3 times
>
> 0 repeated 3 times
>
> 3 repeated 2 times

I have developed a new code based on your help, but my new code solved only the first problem:

```
public static void repeated(int x[]){
        int i, j;
        for(i=0 ; i<x.length ; i++ ){
            int isRepeat = 1;
            for(j=i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--){
                if(x[i] == x[j]){
                    isRepeat ++;
                }
            }
            if(isRepeat == 2){
                System.out.println(x[i] + " repeated " + "? times");
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr []= {7,4,3,0,2,0,5,2,13,2,0,3};
        repeated(arr);
    }
```

then the output:

> 0 repeated ? times
>
> 2 repeated ? times
>
> 3 repeated ? times

Still the counter that i want to do it without any lists or hashmap

Comment: Try to debug properly....

Comment: The inner loop has to traverse forwards. You can't have one going forwards and the other going backwards. They will count more than once.

Comment: I think this is an assignment , but i will give you a hint , your outer loop is fine, there should be two inner loops . first: iterate element from 0 to i-2, if you found any duplicate that means that value has been already processed, break to the outer loop. if you didnt find any duplicate you can start the next loop to identify duplicate, second loop can be started from i to length -1

Answer (score 0):

1. Create `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.
2. For each number in `arr` check if it's in `map.keySet`. If yes, increment the value. If not add with one.
3. For key in `map.keySet` if value > 1, print key + " repeated " + value + " times\n"

Comment: thank you, but i haven't learnt HashMap yet and i don't want to use it in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have the inner loop in the traverse forward, have set of integers to store the already counted one, before checking for the repeat check if you have already exists in the counted if so ignore

```
public static void repeated(int x[])
    {
        int i, j;
        int counter = 0;
        Set<Integer> alreadyCounted = new HashSet<>();
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            boolean isRepeat = false;
            if (!alreadyCounted.contains(x[i]))
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++)
                {
                    if (x[i] == x[j])
                    {
                        isRepeat = true;
                        alreadyCounted.add(x[i]);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                if (isRepeat)
                {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                    System.out.println(x[i] + " repeated " + counter + " times");
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr []= {7,4,3,0,2,0,5,2,13,2,0,3};
        repeated(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int arr[] = { 7, 4, 3, 0, 2, 0, 5, 2, 13, 2, 0, 3 };

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    FindingFreq ob = new FindingFreq();
    for( Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : ob.getList() )
    {
        System.out.println( entry.getKey() + " repeated " + entry.getValue() + " times !" );
    }

}

private List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> getList()
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for( Integer intValue : arr )
    {
        if( map.get( intValue ) == null )
        {
            map.put( intValue, 1 );
        }
        else
        {
            map.put( intValue, map.get( intValue ) + 1 );
        }
    }
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>( map.entrySet() );
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> comp = new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>()
    {

        @Override
        public int compare( Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2 )
        {
            return ( o1.getValue() ).compareTo( o2.getValue() );
        }
    };

    Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> cmp1 = Collections.reverseOrder( comp );
    Collections.sort( list, cmp1 );

    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: thank you, but i don't want to use lists to solve the problem as i haven't studied them yet

Comment: @joeMarko You can use dimensional array i guess for this purpose if you want to use one more array excluding input value.
Value   7 4 3 0 2 0 5 2 13 2 0 3
Repetition 0 0 2 2 2 3 0 2 0 2 2 1
Store values in row column so number 0 has say some n repetition you can store in same column, once you are done with the loop. for new Array iterate and print corresponding repetition.